# How to add multiple comments in add_custom_command of CMake?

Tags: cmake, comments, cmake-custom-command

This question is just out of curiosity as I noticed that only the last comment block was being printed.

```
add_custom_command(
 TARGET target_a
 POST_BUILD
 COMMAND command_A_to_do_something
 COMMENT "Comment A"
 COMMAND command_B_to_do_something_else
 COMMENT "Comment B"
)
```

Only "Comment B" is printed on the console. For this reason, I ended up splitting multiple commands to multiple add_custom_command blocks. Any ideas of how to get all comments printed?

Using CMake v3.5.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do this with CMake's [command line abstraction](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode) for `echo`:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET target_a
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND command_A_to_do_something
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Comment A"
  COMMAND command_B_to_do_something_else
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Comment B"
)
```

Comment: You mean COMMAND instead of COMMENT right? Because COMMENT ${CMAKE_COMMAND} didn't work while the former did. Didn't know about command line abstraction. Thanks.

Comment: @sunam Ups, copy-and-paste failure from my side. And yes, thanks for the correcting it.